# How to Instantiate a model class in another model class?

Tags: typescript

I have one to one relationship in the back-end, and in the Angular, I have two models: `Child` and `ChildPermission` both standalone no extension.

I want to instantiate `ChildPermission` model in the `Child` model but it is giving an undefined error.

Child class:

```
import {ChildPermission} from './childpermission';
export interface Child {

  id: number;
  class_id: number;
  f_name: string;
  l_name: string;
  permission: ChildPermission;
}
```

ChildPermission:

```
export interface ChildPermission {

  id: number;
  walking: boolean;
  biking: boolean;
  player_water: boolean;
  go_parks: boolean;
  go_fields: boolean;
  using_photos: boolean;
}
```

In the component I tried the following:

```
export class ChildAddComponent implements OnInit {

  child: Child = {} as Child;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.child.permission.walking = true;
    console.log(this.child);
  }

}
```

But it returns the following in the console:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.child.permission.walking = true')

Comment: If you are using interface here, you need to initiate the object by assigning each property, like { ... walking: false, ...  }. If you want to go with 'new' approach, change it to class.

Comment: i think youre missing a comment `child: Child = {} as Child;` should read `child: Child = {}// as Child;`

Comment: @wannadream I changed it to the class but still, I have the same error.

Comment: because you probably didnt do `child: Child = new Child()`

Comment: An interface is just template for an Object used by typescript to give compile errors if the data does not meet the requirement. It does not assign its properties with any values .

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I have the same error changing it to `new Child();`

Comment: then it sounds like its not building correctly

Comment: 'this.child.permission.walking = true;', where did you initiate 'permission'?

Comment: @wannadream you dont need to if you instantiate the top level class

Comment: @wannadream I might be missing that part. Where do I need to instantiate it? In the model or component?

Comment: Sticking with interface, you can do 'child: Child = {... permission: { id: 1, walking ... } ...}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go with interface approach, you need assign all required properties like below:

```
child: Child = {
    id: 1,
    class_id: 1,
    ...
    permission: {
        id: 1,
        walking: false,
        ...
    }
}
```

If you switch it to class approach, then do it like below.

```
child = new Child();
```

Inside Child class, initiate permission like this.

```
permission = new ChildPermission();
```

You can refer to many resources to know more about difference between interface and class in TypeScript.
e.g. https://toddmotto.com/classes-vs-interfaces-in-typescript

Comment: doing `child: Child = new Child()` will instantiate `Child` and also `ChildPermissions` at the same time if classes are used for both

Comment: @mast3rd3mon for some reason it was not instantiating it, and an extra instantiating worked.

Comment: probably as you didnt change the permissions interface to a class

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I did.

Comment: then it sounds like it cached the file/build

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I restarted the server but didn't work without that line of code. It is weird.

Comment: 'new Child()' will not initiate 'permission' if you leave it with 'permission: ChildPermission;' inside Child class. Because it means 'permission' is still undefined. Please review OOP knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

Property `permission` doesnt defined in your `child: Child` field. You need to initiate it like this:

```
this.child.permission = {
  id: 1;
  walking: true;
  biking: false;
  player_water: false;
  go_parks: false;
  go_fields: false;
  using_photos: false;
}
```

Or `this.child.permission = getChildPermission()`, where `getChildPermission()` return ChildPermission object.
And after that you can change properties in `this.user.permission`

Comment: this is overkill, assuming both interfaces are actually classes, doing `child: Child = new Child()` will instantiate `Child` and also `ChildPermissions` at the same time

Comment: In this case we dont have class Child, to instantiate it using `new`. I think Child and ChildPermission object getting from REST. Or I`m wrong?

Comment: `"assuming both interfaces are actually classes"` is what i said